# Swift erro na passagem de parâmetros

Tags: swift

```
func imageUploadRequest(param:[String: String] ,myImageView: UIImage)
```

Preciso chamar a função `imageUploadRequest` passando 2 parâmetros, sendo o primeiro um array de string e o segundo uma imagem. Como eu poderia fazer isso? Porque está dando erro ao passar os parâmetros?

```
var up = UploadImageView()
            var request: UploadImageView = UploadImageView()
            request.imageUploadRequest(param, myImageView: self.imageProfile)
```

Comment: Array de String ou Dicionario? se for somente array de string usa só `param:[String]`. Qual erro esta aparecendo nos Logs?

Answer (score 0):

No caso, você deve passar os parâmetros da seguinte maneira:

```
func imageUploadRequest(param:Array<String>,myImageView:UIImage)
```

Tomando por posição que no swift 2.0 é utilizado a especificação do parâmetro de array através do "< >".

Espero ter ajudado.